# Issue while trying to compute the integral for the coefficients of a triangular wave

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I was trying to compute these integrals in order to check if I was correct:

[image]

or in code

```
(1/T) * Integrate[(2*t/T) * (Exp[-I*(2*Pi/T)*k*t]), {t, 0, T/(2)}] + (1/T) * Integrate[(2*(T-t)/T) * (Exp[-I*(2*Pi/T)*k*t]), {t, T/(2), T}]
```

The result I get from Mathematica is this

[image]

Yet I would expect something that looks more like this

[image]

I am not sure if questions of this type have any meaning whatsoever but out of curiosity I would like to know why do I get this result and who is correct in the end.

Comment: Please insert the code, not the images; it is difficult to verify the issue if we have to hand-type everything!

Comment: @JHM I apologize about that, hopefully the edit will solve the issue.

Comment: Apply `FullSimplify` to the answer and it looks a lot like your expected answer (after correcting the syntax errors in your code -- use Exp[] instead of exp()).

Comment: I copied and pasted the current form (perhaps you changed it?) and got the desired answer, `-(1/2) exp j k pi`, using version 10.4.

Comment: I tried fixing some mistakes pointed out by others. I am not a user of Mathematica, so there were quite a few.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Simplify[(1/T)*
   Integrate[2*t/T*Exp[-I*2*Pi/T*k*t], {t, 0, T/2}, 
    Assumptions -> T > 0] + (1/T)*
   Integrate[2*(T - t)/T*Exp[-I*2*Pi/T*k*t], {t, T/2, T}, 
    Assumptions -> 0 < T/2 < T], k \[Element] Integers]

(* (-1 + (-1)^k)/(k^2 Pi^2) *)
```

check your solution

```
Simplify[(Exp[Pi (-I) k] - 1)/(Pi^2 k^2), 
 k \[Element] Integers]

(* (-1 + (-1)^k)/(k^2 \[Pi]^2) *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yours syntax is very bad. [Search and Read this first.](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/?source=nav)

```
sol = (1/T)*Integrate[(2*t/T)*Exp[-I*2*Pi/T*k*t], {t, 0, T/2}] + 
(1/T)*Integrate[(2*(T - t)/T)*Exp[-I*2*Pi/T*k*t], {t, T/2, T}]

FullSimplify[sol]
```

and answer:

> $-\frac{e^{-i \pi  k} (\cos (\pi  k)-1)}{\pi ^2 k^2}$